# Three-tier Farm install, what to use on DB - SP_Farm or SQL_Admin?

Tags: user-accounts, service-account, farm, farm-setup

I'm installing SQL on (by example FARM_DB1) server. I created SP_Farm in AD and added it as admin on machines, and I'll use it on WFE's. But what is best-practice for SQL machine?  Which account to use better:

- use SP_farm
- create SQL_Service, add it in local admins and install from
  him
- leave defaults
  ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you ask for the best practice then:

**Create the SQL_Admin:** The SQL Server service account is used to run SQL Server. It is the service account for the following SQL Server services: MSSQLSERVER SQLSERVERAGENT. SQL Admin on the SQL Server. it should be **domain user** with **Local Administrato**r on the **SQL Server**.

read more about the best practice: [SharePoint 2013 Service Accounts Best Practices Explained](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-service-accounts-best-practices-explained.html)

Comment: Thank You! Hm, but I log in with SP_Farm in this scenario? Or log in with SQL_Admin, install SQL and then grant access to database to SP_Farm?..

Comment: sql-admin should your account for sql server's box. you should install under this account, then grant permission.